# MongoDB/Mongoskin: $addToSet return value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I'm using MongoDB with Mongoskin with a NodeJS server. I'm trying to add an entry in a document's field using `addToSet` to avoid adding duplicates. How do I know whether my add was successful or not?

Checking the return value didn't really help me, it always returned a `1`. I know using mongo shell I can see what I want from the WriteResult. Is there any way to access this using Mongoskin? This is the closest I can get. Are there any ways to do check whether the add was successful or not?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: any updates on this? I always get undefined as return value...